# Question on location of the solutions of $ax^2+bx+c=0$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

> Let $a,b$ and $c$ be real numbers. The equation $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0$ has solutions $α$ and $β$ such that $α<-1$ and $β>1.$  Prove that $$1+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{|b|}{a} < 0.$$

What I noticed was $\frac{f(-1)}{a}<0$ and $\frac{f(1)}{a}<0.$ Furthermore, $\frac{f(-1)f(1)}{a^2}>0$   which implies $(1+\frac{c}{a})^2>\frac{b^2}{a^2}$  I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Just take your first two inequalities and expand them to see what the full expressions are. Compare with what you are being asked to prove.

Comment: $1 + \frac{c}{a} + \frac{|b|}{a}$ is one of $1 + \frac{c}{a} \pm \frac{b}{a} = \frac{f(\pm 1)}{a}$ but both $\frac{f(\pm 1)}{a}$ are negative!

Answer (score 1):

Use the identities for the zeros of the quadratic equation
\begin{align*}
\alpha + \beta &= \frac{-b}{a},\\
\alpha\beta &= \frac{c}{a}.
\end{align*}
Then if $b<0$
$$
1+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{|b|}{a} = \left(\alpha +1\right) + \beta\left(\alpha + 1\right) < 0,
$$
or if $b>0$
$$
1+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{|b|}{a} = \left(1-\beta\right) + \alpha\left(\beta- 1\right) < 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $f(-1)=a-b+c$ and $f(1)=a+b+c.$
The facts that you already observed, namely,
$\frac{f(-1)}{a}<0$ and $\frac{f(1)}{a}<0,$
then imply that
$$1+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b}{a} < 0$$
and
$$1+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b}{a} < 0.$$
Therefore the *greater* of the two formulas on the left sides of these inequalities is negative.

You can finish by proving and applying the fact that
$$
\frac{\lvert b\rvert}{a} \leq 
\left\lvert \frac{b}{a} \right\rvert \
= \max\left\{-\frac{b}{a}, \frac{b}{a}  \right\}.
$$